# Having trouble utilizing an update and insert query in a SQL scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have been given an example SQL question for an upcoming technical interview.  I'm having trouble understanding how to approach / explain the solution to this question.

> A client has a contract that started on 4/4/2018 and ends on 1/1/2029. 
>   The client signs a continuation with changed terms that starts on 2/10/2024, ending on 11/11/2045.
>   Write the queries needed to update the old contract and insert the new contract.

Would I construct simple DB table(s) that contain example records such as: clientID, contract, cStartDate, cEndDate

And then write INSERT INTO and UPDATE queries?  Or are they looking for something different here?

Comment: I see. They just want an update to amend the end date of the first contract , and an insert to provide the start and end dates if the continuation

Comment: @Strawberry, how would an insert work, would I need two tables?  One for the client and one for the contracts associated with clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you can create a table with the fields  contractID, clientID, cStartDate, cEndDate, notes, status

This way you can simply insert new contract details to the table and update the status field, so that the current, active contract have a unique status, For example, 0 -> archived, 1 -> active, etc.

Or if you prefer that you don't need the historic data, you can then omit the status field and simply update the start and end date using the clientID and contractID ( if a client is having multiple contracts )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a query like this,

Update Table -->

```
UPDATE <YOUR_CONTRACT_TABLE> 
SET cStartDate = '2-10-2024', cEndDate= '11-11-2045'
WHERE id=<YOUR_CONTRACT_ID> ;
```

Insert to the Table -->

```
INSERT INTO <YOUR_CONTRACT_TABLE> (id,clientID, contract, cStartDate, cEndDate)
VALUES (<YOUR_CONTRACT_ID>,<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>, <YOUR_CONTRACT_NAME>, '3-3-2026', '11-11-2039');
```

Comment: That updates any contract that happened to start on the same date, not just for that particular client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't meaningfully answer that question without knowing the relevant table definitions, relvar predicates and business rules. There's not enough information. You can guess and make assumptions (i.e. define your own table(s) and rules), but if that's the point of the question, it ought to have said so.